# Swap two columns between two tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables: `Jobs`:

```
JobId   ApiId1   JobType
1       3        1
2       4        3
3       6        3
```

And `TypeThreeJobs`, for type-specific data

```
JobId   ApiId2
2       5
3       7
```

Where applicable, I need to swap the values in `Api2` and `Api3`

```
JobId   ApiId1   JobType | ApiId2
1       3        1       |
2       5        3       | 4
3       7        3       | 6
```

What's the most efficient way to do this? I have an answer below, but was wondering if there was a more efficient version (e.g. no need for table variables).

Comment: I don't think so - you can only edit one table's worth of data at a time during a view. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My working solution is to use a table variable:

```
INSERT INTO @SwapValues
SELECT Jobs.JobId, ApiId1, ApiId2
FROM Jobs INNER JOIN TypeThreeJobs
ON Jobs.JobId = TypeThreeJobs.JobId

UPDATE Jobs
Set ApiId1 = SV.ApiId2
FROM @SwapValues SV INNER JOIN Jobs
ON Jobs.JobId = SV.JobId

UPDATE TypeThreeJobs
Set ApiId2 = SV.ApiId1
FROM @SwapValues SV INNER JOIN Jobs
ON Jobs.JobId = SV.JobId
```